# What is the meaning of the two numbers in the paper identifier of EDAS?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission

I have submitted a paper to a conference via [EDAS](https://www.edas.info/). The conference asked me for the "paper number" in its own registration form (independent from EDAS).

On EDAS my paper has an identifier composed by two numbers, in the form #XX (XXX..XXX), where the Xs are digits. What is the meaning of the two numbers?

I went quickly through the [EDAS glossary](https://edas.info/doc/glossary.html), but I did not find the answer.